# Bootstrap Navbar dropdown menu works on HTML document but not on PHP document

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, button, navbar

A drop-down menu I created with Twitter Bootstrap works on HTML documents but will not drop down on PHP documents. [Here is a PHP document](http://colorfulcards.org/contact.php) where you can see see what I mean. When I click the "more" tab, it does not drop down.

Why doesn't this menu work on both HTML and PHP documents?

Here is the page source:

```
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">

   <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="navbar-header">

         <a href"" class="navbar-brand">Colorful Cards</a>

         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li class=""><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>

        <li class=""><a href="thatonepage.html">Past Cards</a></li>

        <li class="active"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">More<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
             <li class="inverse-dropdown"><a href="bibliography.html">Bibliography</a></li>
             <li class="divider inverse-dropdown"></li>
             <li class="inverse-dropdown"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
             <li class="divider inverse-dropdown"></li>
             <li class="inverse-dropdown"><a href="">Coming Soon...</a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (bootstrap-dropdown.js, line 0)

Comment: I'm sorry @mmgross but does that mean the page didn't load at all for you? Could you please elaborate what that error means and how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, that might not even be the error, but the page loaded fine, however bootstrap-dropdown.js did not load. There could be another cause: You included 2 different, possibly conflicting, versions of bootstrap.js, one in the `<head>` and one near the bottom of your page.

Comment: unfortunately that is not the issue, but thanks @mmgross

Comment: On second try, it did work, Thank you so much @mmgross I've been trying to figure that out all week :)

Comment: @LiamDiGregorio You should write up an answer to explain how you solved this issue. Unfortunately, it's not clear now what was even wrong, since on your example page the menu is now working. The more details you can add that will help someone else to solve the same issue in the future, the better.

Comment: Thank you @Air for the suggestion. My issue that I was having was that although all the css classes were working in my document from bootstrap, so elements such as the dropdown button, was not working. If you are having this issue or a similar problem, the reason may be the same as mine which was that I had the bootstrap link on my page twice and they were different updates. So because of this, the issue was not with the .php but the bootstrap link(s).